# CSS Overlapping Issue With Divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something with CSS and HTML which doesn't seem to be working for me. This is my CSS and HTML:

```
#site p {
 margin-left: -625px;
 margin-right: -400px;
}

#wikicontent {
 top: 331px;
 left: 144px;
 position:fixed;
 background: #E0E0E0;
 border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
 height: 100px;
}

#site {
 border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 background: #fff;
 width: 1075px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
 padding: 2px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
}

#site h3 {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 text-align: left;
}


<html>
<div id="site">
<div id="wikicontent">
<h3>Testing</h3>
</div>
<p>This is some really long text for an example. And I'm still writing an example. This is really looooooooooooooooong. Looooooooooong. This is just an example of the text.</p>
</div>
</html>
```

The problem is the div 'wikicontent' is overlapping the text, preventing it from being shown. Is there a way to set a border, to prevent the overlapping?

Here's an example of what's happening: http://prntscr.com/6q1p9m

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle, so we can solve your problem faster and easier?

Comment: why did you set wiki... to be fixed?

Comment: @Legends It's not needed at the moment, but when the div 'site' becomes longer with more text, I need the div 'wikicontent' to scroll down with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo !

There you go : http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/wxe0L4xb/

This isn't responsive at all though. I had to play with margins, display and width percentage to render it to your example.

```
#site p {
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wikicontent {
    position:fixed;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    height: 68px;
    width: 10%;
}
#site {
    border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 1075px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
}
#site h3 {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Seriously hope its helping you work around your problem.

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks Bladepianist, I appreciate it!